# Table of contents in Beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, backgrounds

I have seen a nice looking table of contents in a Beamer presentation. There were some formulas, pictures, graphs situated across the frame in a shadow background. Any idea how to do this?[image]

Comment: What did you see? A background picture?

Comment: Could you upload as picture the frame you saw?

Comment: You can refer to [how can i upload an image to be included in a question or answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2136/how-can-i-upload-an-image-to-be-included-in-a-question-or-answer).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `background` template; the background is an image that can be included with the usual `\includegraphics` command; the opacity is controlled by putting the image inside a `\node` with the help of `TikZ`; after the ToC, the template is again redefined to suppress the image:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
   \tikz\node[opacity=0.3] at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{ctanlion}};}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{}
\section{Test Section One}
\begin{frame}
Contents of section one
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Two}
\begin{frame}
Contents of section two
\end{frame}

\section{Test Section Three}
\begin{frame}
Contents of section three
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

CTAN lion drawing by Duane Bibby.

Comment: ImageMagick's `convert` can help us to convert a PDF file into a PNG image tightly (rather than pressing PRINTSCREEN that sometimes leaves unnecessary borders). Invoke `convert -density <integer value> -alpha <choose: on, off, remove> <input filename>.pdf <output filename>.png`. Remarks: `-alpha remove` will remove the transparency better than `-alpha off`. Inserting `%02d` in the output filename makes 2-digit counter `00, 01, ..., 99` attached to the output filename when the PDF contains more than one page.

Comment: @GarbageCollector ah, thank you very much for that. I simply open the document with okular, seclect the desired region and save it as an image.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{background.tex}
\documentclass[pstricks,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-\psPi,-2)(\psPi,2)
    \psplot[algebraic,plotpoints=1500]{-\psPi}{\psPi}{sin(15*x)*cos(13*x)+cos(5*x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\AtBeginDocument
{
    \immediate\write18{latex background}
    \immediate\write18{dvips background}
    \immediate\write18{ps2pdf background.ps}
}
\begin{document}
\bgroup
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{background}}
\begin{frame}[t]{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
\egroup

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}[t]{Who am I?}
I am a Garbage Collector.
\end{frame}

\section{At a glance}
\begin{frame}[t]{What is your hobby?}
Coding!
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Edit: Compile the code with `pdflatex --shell-escape filename`.