# Force a beamercolorbox to the bottom of a frame with no margin

Tags: beamer, positioning

I would like to occasionally put some notes at the bottom of a frame using a `beamercolorbox`. I am trying to force this box to be exactly at the bottom, without any blank space before the end of the frame.

I am currently using this code:

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
% ...
\vskip0pt plus 1filll
\begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=6pt,center,wd=\paperwidth]{block body}
Text
\end{beamercolorbox}
```

However the result looks like this (you can note some extra white space between the box and the end of the frame):

[image]

I have removed any content from the footline. Actually I'd also be happy with the box overlapping with the footline, as I use it for the frame number only and I could adjust the padding in the box to avoid the text to overlap.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

I eventually found a (partial) solution, inspired by [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/110727/220832).

I defined a new command `\bottomtext`:

```
\newcommand\bottomtext[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,anchor=south] at ([yshift=0pt]current page.south)
{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=3ex,dp=2ex,center]{block body}
\hfill\parbox[c][7ex][c]{0.8\paperwidth}{\footnotesize#1}\hfill\null
\end{beamercolorbox}
};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
%...
\bottomtext{Text goes here}
```

It works, but the height of the box must be manually adjusted according to the content.